# iOS view borders sometimes thicker

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

If I place multiple buttons in a `StackView` without space between them (Fill) and add a border to each button, the borders are not equal in width.

I do this for all buttons:

```
button.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor().CGColor
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I'm guessing this is because the border is drawn inside the buttons view not outside. But this does not explain why it is thicker for some buttons and not for all of them.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you check in real device????

Comment: how could I not check that... on a real device everything is perfect. And after testing that, I noticed that I have my simulator scaled to 75%. Setting it to 100% also solves the problem. 

Thanks! Please add an answer so I can mark it as solved

Comment: @MikeyB it's simulator artifact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is problem with simulator scale .. check this in your real device or set your simulator scale to 100% .. it will solve your problem